# Template class with static members across multiple DLL/DSO

Tags: c++, templates, dll, static, shared-libraries

There were many questions about C++ template classes which contain static member variables, as well as about exporting them from dynamic libraries or shared objects. But this one is a bit deeper: what to do if there are multiple shared objects, each of them having its own set of instantiations but possibly using instantiations from another shared object?

Consider the following example code:

```
/* file: common.h */

#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINT fprintf (stderr, "(template %d) %d -> %d\n", parameter, data, new_data)

template <int parameter>
class SharedClass
{
    static int data;
public:
    static void Set(int new_data) { PRINT; data = new_data; }
};

template <int parameter>
int SharedClass<parameter>::data = parameter;


/* file: library1.h */

extern template class SharedClass<1>;
void Library1Function();


/* file: library1.cpp */

#include "common.h"
#include "library1.h"
#include "library2.h"

template class SharedClass<1>;

void Library1Function()
{
    SharedClass<1>::Set (100);
    SharedClass<2>::Set (200);
}


/* file: library2.h */

extern template class SharedClass<2>;
void Library2Function();


/* file: library2.cpp */

#include "common.h"
#include "library1.h"
#include "library2.h"

template class SharedClass<2>;

void Library2Function()
{
    SharedClass<1>::Set (1000);
    SharedClass<2>::Set (2000);
}


/* file: main.cpp */

#include "common.h"
#include "library1.h"
#include "library2.h"

int main()
{
    Library1Function();
    Library2Function();
    SharedClass<1>::Set (-1);
    SharedClass<2>::Set (-2);
}
```

Let's then assume we build the two libraries and an application using GCC:

```
$ g++ -fPIC -fvisibility=default -shared library1.cpp -o lib1.so
$ g++ -fPIC -fvisibility=default -shared library2.cpp -o lib2.so
$ g++ -fvisibility=default main.cpp -o main -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -l1 -l2
```

And then run the executable, we'll get the following result:

```
$ ./main
(template 1) 1 -> 100
(template 2) 2 -> 200
(template 1) 100 -> 1000
(template 2) 200 -> 2000
(template 1) 1000 -> -1
(template 2) 2000 -> -2
```

Which means that both libraries and the executable access the same per-template static storage.
If we run "nm -C" on the binaries, we'll see that each static member is defined only once and in the corresponding library:

```
$ nm -C -A *.so main | grep ::data
lib1.so:0000000000001c30 u SharedClass<1>::data
lib2.so:0000000000001c30 u SharedClass<2>::data
```

But I've got some questions.

1. Why, if we remove the `extern template class ...` from both headers, we'll see that the static members are present in each binary, but the test application will continue to work properly?

   ```
   $ nm -C -A *.so main | grep ::data
   lib1.so:0000000000001c90 u SharedClass<1>::data
   lib1.so:0000000000001c94 u SharedClass<2>::data
   lib2.so:0000000000001c94 u SharedClass<1>::data
   lib2.so:0000000000001c90 u SharedClass<2>::data
   main:0000000000401e48 u SharedClass<1>::data
   main:0000000000401e4c u SharedClass<2>::data
   ```
2. Is it possible to build this under MSVC?
   Or, more specifically, how to deal with `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` to make some instantiations exported, and some - imported?
3. And, finally: is this an example of undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer point 1: When the dynamic linker resolves symbols, it uses a list of modules to link against.  The first module loaded is checked first, then the second, and so on.

IIRC, when the `data` member is used in main, lib1.so, and lib2.so, this is still treated as a dynamic symbol reference, even though the member is declared in the same module.  So when the linker goes to resolve the symbols when you run the program, all three modules wind up using the `data` member implementation in just one of the three modules: whichever was loaded first.  The other two pairs are still loaded into memory, but are unused.

(Try `std::cout << &(SharedClass<n>::data) << std::endl` in all three modules; the address printed should be the same for all six cases.)

To answer point 3, I don't believe this behavior is undefined at all.  What happens exactly depends on your system's dynamic linker, but I don't know of any linker that wouldn't handle this situation in exactly the same way.

I can't speak to point 2 since I don't have a whole lot of experience with MSVC.

Comment: Yes, the addresses are the same in both cases. Thank you.